# Generate Django Models from swagger schema

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, swagger, schema

I have a swagger docs - openapi.yaml
My task is to write an API. I have schemas in openapi.yaml.

My question is how to convert schemas from openapi.yaml to Django Models?

I have figured out that there is fastapi-codegen for FastAPI. But I use Django Rest Framework, are there any similar generators for DRF?

Comment: This is not really an answer - but I tried this app and after installing some undeclared dependencies (click, jinja2, six and swagger-parser), I found that it only parses Swagger 2.0 https://github.com/praekelt/swagger-django-generator